# How can I rearrange the order of edges in an igraph plot?

Tags: r, igraph

I'm trying to make a network plot in igraph that highlights certain important edges by coloring them differently than the others. For large graphs, they often get buried under the others. For example:

```
library(igraph)
test <- barabasi.game(200,m=2)
E(test)$color <- "gray"
E(test)[1]$color <- "red"
sort(order(E(test)$color)[E(test)],decreasing=TRUE)
plot(test,
     vertex.label=NA,
     vertex.shape="none",
     vertex.size=0,
     edge.arrow.mode=0,
     edge.width=2)
```

gives me a plot where the single red edge is at the bottom.
[image: this plot makes me sad]
If I choose to color a higher-numbered edge (rather than #1) it has a better chance of not being buried.

So it seems to me that one option is to somehow re-order the edges. I tried

```
E(test) <- E(test)[order(E(test)$color)]
```

but that gets me an "invalid indexing" error. Any ideas about what else I should try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

igraph plots the edges in the order they appear in the graph's edge list, so you are right, edges with higher IDs will be drawn on top of the edges with lower IDs. Unfortunately igraph does not provide an easy way to reorder the edges of the graph (although it has a function named `permute.vertices`, which will allow you to permute the vertices), so the only way I can think of right now is that you need to construct another graph in which the edges are in the "right order". `make_graph` ensures that the edges are stored in the graph exactly in the order you specify them, and I think so does `graph_from_data_frame`.

Another option (if you don't want to reconstruct the entire graph) is to plot the graph twice: first you plot the "not-so-important" edges and set the width of the important ones to zero, then you plot the important edges on top.

If you would like edge permutations to be supported in an upcoming version of igraph, please [file a feature request](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues) on Github.

Comment: Thanks, Tamás! The plotting-twice solution is working best for me. I use `set.seed()` to make sure my layout is reproducible, and after plotting once, I use `E(test)[E(test)$color=="gray"]$color  <- NA` to make sure the gray edges get hidden, and `add=TRUE` in the second call to `plot()`.

Comment: You can also call a layout function explicitly and store its result in a variable - then you can pass this variable later on in the `layout=...` argument of `plot()`.

Comment: You can also generate a layout once and then store it to the graph. If you set g$layout attribute, the plot will automatically use the layout stored there. In this case, you would store the layout to the graph and then set the new graph layout equal to the old graph layout.

Comment: hi @wmsmith I have test your suggestion using plot.igraph with add=TRUE and layout with the old graph. But the new plot give wrong place when compared with the old one. I haven't checked the reason.

Answer (score 3):

You can reconstruct the graph with the edges reordered using "as_data_frame" and "graph_from_data_frame" fairly easily in conjunction with the dplyr and tidyr packages:

```
new_graph=graph_from_data_frame(d=as_data_frame(old_graph,what="edges") %>%
    arrange(desc(ordering_attribute)),
    vertices=as_data_frame(old_graph,what="vertices"))
```

if you had a layout stored on the old graph you would need to transfer it manually...

```
new_graph$layout = old_graph$layout
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why `E(test) <- E(test)[order(E(test)$color)]` can not work out is that we are not allowed to assign an 'igraph.es' variable to another existing one or itself; however, we can create a new 'igraph.es' varibale using: `a <- E(test)[order(E(test)$color)]`. Thus, we need create a new graph to inherit a new order of edges from the orginal graph:

```
library(igraph)
test <- barabasi.game(200,m=2)
E(test)$color <- "gray"
E(test)[1]$color <- "red"

# to make a new graph:test2 whose edges are descended from the ordering edges of the orginal graph:test
test2 <- make_graph(as.vector(t(get.edgelist(test)[order(E(test)$color),])))
# to assign the attribute value to the edges of the new graph
E(test2)$color <- E(test)$color[order(E(test)$color)]

plot(test2,
 vertex.label=NA,
 vertex.shape="none",
 vertex.size=0,
 edge.arrow.mode=0,
 edge.width=2)
```

As the plot shows, the red edge becomes the toppest one:
[image: plot of the new graph:test2]

Answer (score 0):

Or you could simply rearrange your data based on the variable you wish to be ordered and then feed it to igraph