# extract community membership after community detection in igraph (R)

Tags: r, igraph

I am having some trouble extracting community membership after running community detection algorithms in `igraph`. The `membership` vector stored does not seem to correspond to community membership found by the algorithm. I suspect I am missing something but documentation is thin, any help appreciated.

My example:

Create a weighted graph with three communities and two components:

```r
v1 <- c(1,1,2,3,4,4,6,7,8,9)
v2 <- c(2,3,3,4,5,6,5,8,9,7)
weight <- c(3,3,2,1,3,3,2,2,2,3)

graph <- data.frame(v1,v2)
g <- graph.data.frame(graph, directed=FALSE)
```

The communities in the above graph are vertices (1,2,3), (4,5,6), and (7,8,9). And indeed when we run a community detection algorithm, this is what it finds:

```r
cd <- fastgreedy.community(g)
plot(cd,g, edge.width=weight)
str(cd)
```

Gives output:

```
IGRAPH clustering fast greedy, groups: 3, mod: 0.56
 groups:
  1
  [1] "7" "8" "9"

  2
  [1] "4" "6" "5"

  3
  [1] "1" "2" "3"`
```

[and this nice picture of the graph split up into communities.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0NBX.png)

However, when I try to access `cd$membership` or `cutat()`, it's a different picture:

```r
cd$membership
cutat(cd, steps=which.max(cd$modularity)-1)
```

both give

```
[1] 3 3 3 2 2 1 1 1 2
```

Am I wrong in interpreting the above as indicating community membership of each vertex? It seems as though it is (correctly) assigning (1,2,3) to community 3, but incorrectly grouping (4,5,9) and (6,7,8) together.

Comment: maybe use `membership(cd)`?

Answer (score 1):

The seeming missmatch stems from the order `igraph` reads and assigns vertex ids (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33444188/how-can-i-rearrange-the-order-of-edges-in-an-igraph-plot) for reference).

Let's take a look at the order of vertices as provided by the `graph`-object:

```
> unlist(graph, use.names = F)               # identical to c(v1, v2)
 [1] 1 1 2 3 4 4 6 7 8 9 2 3 3 4 5 6 5 8 9 7
```

In this sequence the `5` appears only *after* `1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9`. This is the resulting vertex-sequence upon removing duplicate entries:

```
> unique(unlist(graph, use.names = F))
[1] 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 5
```

or using `igraph`:

```
> V(g)
+ 9/9 vertices, named, from 3bae324:
[1] 1 2 3 4 6 7 8 9 5
```

Which aligns nicely with the communities found in your example:

```
> sort(membership(cd))
7 8 9 4 6 5 1 2 3         # vertex name
1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3         # community
```

Since the sequences match you could assign the membership as an vertex-attribute like this (as proposed by @chinsoon12):

```
V(g)$community <- membership(cd)
```

Comment: Thanks. Something else I discovered is to do this:
`community <- cd$membership`; `v <- as_ids(V(g))`; `vcom <- data.frame(v,community)`