# How to convert membership to dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

Following code returns nodes in this format

```
> membership(cluster_edge_betweenness(g))
 2  3  4  5  6  9 10 11 12  1  7  8 
 1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3  3  1  2  2
```

How do I convert community membership for each node to a data frame?

```
> data.frame(membership(cluster_edge_betweenness(g)))
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"membership"’ to a data.frame
```

I intend to store it to csv later. Thanks for answer.

Comment: `as.data.frame`?

Comment: `
> as.data.frame(membership(cluster_edge_betweenness(g)))
Error in as.data.frame.default(membership(cluster_edge_betweenness(g))) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"membership"’ to a data.frame
`

Does not work :-/

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58022160/extract-community-membership-after-community-detection-in-igraph-r) help?  See, in particular the comment from the OP relating to the answer given.  Also, please provide a minimal reproducible example ([this post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) may help).  I'm guessing your question relates to the `igraph` package, but you've not provided enough information to be sure.

Comment: Thank that solves mi problem perfectly.

community <- cluster_edge_betweenness(g)$membership
v <- as_ids(V(g))
vcom <- data.frame(v,community)
write.table(vcom,  file = "name.csv", sep = ";", dec = ",", row.names = FALSE)

Comment: One more thing I need to fix :-D. The csv is in folowing format:
"v";"community"
"2";1
"3";1
"4";2
"5";2
"6";2
"9";2
"10";3
"11";3
"12";3
"1";1
"7";2
"8";2

How to I remove the quotes from "v" column. I mean the numbers I dont care about the header.